# Is it possible to remove NAs for each pairwise comparison in correlation() function of correlation package in R?

Tags: r, correlation, na

I'd like to know how to remove `NA`s for pairwise comparisons in the `correlation()` function of the `correlation` package in **R**. *Other alternatives are welcome. I'm aware of `rcorr()` from the `Hmisc` package, but I need the output in long (tidy) format.*

This would be the equivalent of `cor(x, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')`.

As I need both the `p.value` and `estimate`, `cor()` is not suitable, and painfully `cor.test()` doesn't have `use = 'pairwise.complete.obs'` as a parameter.

Specifically, due to the large nature of the data `cor.test(x, na.action = 'na.omit')` excessively removes entries from the Pearson correlation analysis, which is why I want this to be performed according to the pairwise comparisons rather than across the entire dataset.

Comment: I don‘t think there‘s an option to set missings in this package. You could either try to adjust the package code and compile your own version (difficult) or you could try to get correlations e.g. from the corrr package and calculate the p values on your own (for Pearson cors it‘s pretty straightforward, i.e you convert correlations to z values, compare the z values and derive the p calues from it).

Comment: See e.g here how to calculate the z calue of the difference (at the bottom): https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/formulas.aspx?id=104

Comment: @deschen Thanks for highlighting the ```corrr``` package I'll have a look, but I think I might try to figure out an efficient way to convert/create a long (tidy) format data frame from the separate r and p-value matrices from the ```Hmisc``` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so just for the fun of it. Using the `corrr` package would give you some nice tidy data options, i.e. you can get the correlations a) in tidy format and b) in long format. It can also give you the number of pairwise complete obs (`pair_n`).

And from there, it's relatively easy to a) calculate the t-value for the correlation being different from zero and b) the corresponding p-value. Note in my comment above, I assumed you wanted to calculate the difference between two correlations. However, I think you just want the normal p-value of the correlations.

## 1. Create a toy data set with missings:

```
set.seed(1)
mtcars_NA <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(row_number() %in% sample(1:32, 5), NA_real_, .)))
```

## 2. Calculate the correlations, append with the sample size and get t/p values

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

mtcars_NA %>%
  correlate() %>%
  shave() %>%
  stretch() %>%
  filter(!is.na(r)) %>%
  left_join(mtcars_NA %>%
              pair_n %>%
              as.data.frame() %>%
              rownames_to_column("x") %>%
              pivot_longer(-x,
                           values_to = "n",
                           names_to  = "y"),
            by = c("x", "y")) %>%
  mutate(t_value = r / sqrt((1 - r^2) / (n -2)),
         p_value = 2*pt(q = abs(t_value), df = n-2, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 55 x 6
   x     y          r     n t_value      p_value
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 mpg   cyl   -0.851    22   -7.23 0.000000534 
 2 mpg   disp  -0.864    23   -7.87 0.000000107 
 3 mpg   hp    -0.785    23   -5.80 0.00000929  
 4 mpg   drat   0.684    22    4.19 0.000449    
 5 mpg   wt    -0.882    24   -8.78 0.0000000122
 6 mpg   qsec   0.434    23    2.21 0.0385      
 7 mpg   vs     0.742    23    5.07 0.0000511   
 8 mpg   am     0.549    22    2.94 0.00814     
 9 mpg   gear   0.476    23    2.48 0.0218      
10 mpg   carb  -0.640    23   -3.81 0.00101     
# ... with 45 more rows
```

## 3. Let's compare the first correlation to the cor.test function

```
cor.test(mtcars_NA$cyl, mtcars_NA$mpg)
```

which gives:

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mtcars_NA$cyl and mtcars_NA$mpg
t = -7.2326, df = 20, p-value = 5.337e-07
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9363704 -0.6687359
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.8505393
```

So that's the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exceptional and comprehensive. As a side observation, it appears that pipes are being used within functions - if that's the case I was completely unaware of that functionality. I'm not particularly familiar with the power of the pipe operator. Does the very first element of the chain ```mtcars_NA``` now return the final ```tibble``` ouput, or should I assign to an object at the very beginning, e.g. ```output_cor <- mtcars_NA %>%``` ?

Comment: The latter one. You need to assign it to an object. The current code just prints it to the console.